# When we can use refl?

Tags: agda

I am confused with the context related to identity type in HoTT

> In particular, for a family $C : (a =_A a) \to U$ dependent on a loop, we cannot apply path induction and consider only the case for $C(\text{refl}_a)$, and consequently, we cannot prove that all loops are reflexivity.

and

> In other words, a path $p : x = x$ may be not equal to reflexivity as an element of $(x = x)$,

Then I try to verify the above sentences in agda, I have written following codes

```hs
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

postulate
    x : Set
    y : Set

eq₁ : x ≡ x → Set
eq₁ refl = x

eq₂ : {z : Set} → x ≡ z → Set
eq₂ refl = x

eq₃ : x ≡ y → Set
eq₃ x=y = {!  !}
```

My problem is why we can just care the case $\text{refl}_x$ in `eq₁`, it seems to be contradictory to the second quote ? I can understand `refl` is just a instance constructor of identity type.

Then in `eq₃`, we can not use refl to substitute `x=y`. Can explain some details in these three `eq`?

Comment: Agda by default uses axiom K, which implies uniqueness of identity proofs and is therefore incompatible with HoTT. If you disable it with `--without-K`, then `eq₁` won't be accepted any more (but `eq₂` will be, because `z` is a "free" endpoint).

Comment: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2628136.2628139 this paper explains pretty well

Comment: I wrote about this on my blog, see [the elements of inductive types](https://math.andrej.com/2013/08/28/the-elements-of-an-inductive-type/).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have enough knowledge to work out what's going on with `eq₁`. It is accepted in standard Agda, but not with flags `--without-K`, `--cubical`, or `--cubical-compatible`.

As for `eq₃`, this pattern matching failure is more contingent on aspects traditionally thought of as “implementation details”. To start, in Agda, postulates are implemented essentially as (function) definitions without bodies. Therefore, whatever applies to postulates generally also applies to definitions. With that in mind, consider what happens when we replace the postulates `x` and `y` by these definitions:

```hs
data Bool : Set where true false : Bool

x : Bool → Bool
x _ = false

y : Bool → Bool
y true = false
y false = true
```

Then, if we have a variable `q : x ≡ y` and try to match it against `refl`, we have to unify `x` and `y`. The question is: Do we turn `x` into `y` or `y` into `x`? This matters, for example, when trying to work out the behaviour of the following function `foo` (where `refl : {x : Bool → Bool} → x ≡ x`, and thus `z` is bound to whatever common unifier is chosen between `x` and `y`).

```hs
foo : x ≡ y → Bool
foo (refl {x = z}) = z false
```

One could argue that `x` and `y` are unequal, and so they should anti-unify, allowing us to use the absurd pattern `()` rather than `refl`. However, their inequality is a matter of proof, and if you consider functions from the natural numbers instead of the Booleans, you can soon reach undecidability.

In contrast, in `eq₂`, we know that `z` is a bound variable, and thus cannot have a definition. The pattern `refl` unifies `x` and `z` using the substitution `[z ↦ x]`.

Comment: What happends when `x` and `z` are both bound ?

Comment: @maplgebra You mean `x` and `y`? They unify into a notionally fresh bound variable – like the `z` in my example.

Comment: I see, it finally makes sense.